# Word for counter-efficient

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe the feature my iPad has that is counter-efficient. I'm positive there is a word that means counter-efficient. Does anybody know what that word is?

Comment: Do you mean "inefficient"?

Comment: I tried using *inefficient* but I meant to say it was the opposite of efficient. To my understanding *inefficient* means not efficient, *counter-efficient* means not efficient

Comment: so they mean the same. good, problem solved!

Comment: If you want to say that a specific feature of your iPad doesn't perform its task well, then your word is "inefficient".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is [counterproductive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/counterproductive) *- tending to hinder or act against the achievement of an aim.*

Comment: Aha I know this word, I wonder why I didn't think of it. Perfect!